# Delete element that called onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a generic function that removes anything that calls it.
My code is as follows:

```js
function deletethis(n){
//n is unused in this shortened snippet
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deletethis(5)">Click to remove</button>
```

Expected behaviour: the button gets removed.

Actual behaviour: Error Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined

Comment: What's the `5` for in `deletethis(5)`?

Comment: `this` doesn't get passed automatically into in-line event handlers.

Comment: the `5` is an identifier for the overlying div a couple of hiererarchies up. With the suggestion of @koFTT I will give the button their ids as "nbutton". (this html will be all auto generated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James pointed out in the comments. `this` doesn't get passed automatically. Try this

```js
function deletethis(ele, n){
//n is unused in this shortened snippet
ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deletethis(this, 5)">Click to remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the ID to this function, and it should work :)

```
function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Aw man I was fearing that this would be my only option. They should add my method lol.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use in-line event listeners and `this` will be set properly:

```js
function deletethis(n){
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", deletethis);
```

```html
<button>Click to remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of events also,

```js
function deletethis(event) {
event.currentTarget.remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='deletethis(event)'>hello</button>
```